# Euler characteristic of circle intersections

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

What are Euler Characteristics of the following shapes in $\mathbb R^2 ?$

Circles (2,3,4) have two arc  radii $(R>r).$ Difficulty was in finding its value for tangential contact case 3) using Gauss-Bonnet thm so  that by changing center distance $c$ we can arrive at case 2 or case 4 as a function of center distance $c$.

The tangential case seems to evaluate to $0$ by Euler formula and to $1$ with Gauss-Bonnet thm. So please help in correct calculation.

[image]

Comment: You don't have to use Gauss bonnet to find the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Please indicate how to find it without using GB thm.

Comment: Just give them a triangulation and calculate $V-E+F$.

Comment: @JohnMa Ma Yes, but should n't we be getting the same χ either by above Euler formula or by the GB throrem? In the third case of tangent  we have zero χ by above formula, but by GB thm approach it implies zero rotation with an arbitrary pole for continuous curves, how so? Can you indicate how the two approaches yield identical results?